# Limit of a fraction of double factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, factorial

How can we show that

$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} U_n = 0
\end{align*}$

where

$\begin{align*}
U_n = \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}=\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2}\frac{n-5}{n-4}\cdots
\end{align*}$
terminates at $\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$ (odd) or $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$ (even).

At first glance I thought it was 1 because each individual multiplied fraction goes to 1 as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Mahthematica says this is not case, however.

Does it help if I write it in recurrence relation?

$\begin{align*}
U_{n+2} = \frac{n+1}{n+2}U_n\\
U_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{U_n}
\end{align*}$

Comment: This question is better suited for Math SE. You should probably also indicate what definition you are using for $n!!$ when $n$ is even; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Even_arguments

Comment: Terribly sorry from a newbie. Has exerted to clarify the question.

Comment: (Again a newbie doesn't know how to use this) Thanks @Ma Ming. Can't imagine how stupid I wrote a hint for myself and I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observe the following elementary inequality
\begin{gather*}
\frac{m}{m+1}<\sqrt{\frac{m}{m+2}},\qquad \forall m\in\mathbb{N}
\end{gather*}
where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of all the positive integers.

In the case of $n$ is even, we have, by using the above inequality,
\begin{align*}
0<U_n&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\cdot\frac{2n-1}{2n}\\
&<\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{5}{7}}\cdot\cdots\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2n-3}{2n-1}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
\end{align*}
and in the case of $n$ is odd, we have similarly
\begin{align*}
0<U_n&=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{7}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}\cdot\frac{2n}{2n+1}\\
&<\sqrt{\frac{2}{4}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{4}{6}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{6}{8}}\cdot\cdots\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2n-2}{2n }}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2n }{2n+2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2n+2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
\end{align*}
In summary, we have verified that 
\begin{gather*}
0<U_n<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{gather*}

Then by utilizing the squeezing test and the fact that 
\begin{gather*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0,
\end{gather*}
we can get that 
\begin{gather*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=0.
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. $\{U_n\}_{n \in \text{even}}$ and $\{U_n\}_{n\in \text{odd}}$ are decreasing, limits exist.
2. $U_n U_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}$, let $n$ go to infinity.

Comment: can you let me know how to prove that the sequence $\big(U_n\big)$ is decreasing? I have tried, but was stuck. Thanks a lot.

Comment: edited. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even, use the inequality $1-x\le e^{-x}$ to see
$$
0\le U_n = \frac12\frac34\frac56\cdots\frac{n-1}n\le {\textstyle\exp(-\frac12)\exp(-\frac14)\exp(-\frac16)\cdots\exp(-\frac1n)=\exp -\left(\frac12+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1n\right)}.
$$
The series $\sum_{k=\rm even}^n\frac1k$ diverges to $\infty$, so the subsequence $(U_n)_{n\in \rm even}$ tends to zero. Similarly argue that the odd-indexed terms of $(U_n)$ tend to zero. These two facts imply that $U_n\to0$.

As an aside, it is not enough to observe that the odd-indexed terms of $(U_n)$ are decreasing, the even-indexed terms are decreasing, and that $U_nU_{n+1}\to 0$. A counterexample is the sequence
$$
U_n:=\begin{cases} \frac1n&\text{$n$ even}\\
\frac12+\frac1n&\text{$n$ odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: How did you dig out this question though? It was a challenge set by a Maths course professor in the university. And now I have graduated for over 2 years already.

Comment: @user2513881 The search query *limit double factorials* doesn't return many results. (Congratulations on graduating!)