# function defined by a series involving double factorials and $\cos$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $$ g(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k} \cos(\pi x)^{2k} \frac{(2k-2)!!}{(2k-1)!!}$$ I think this series converges because
$$ |g(x)| \leq \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k} \frac{(2k-2)!!}{(2k-1)!!} < \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}} < \infty$$ where we used the fact that $\frac{n!!}{(n+1)!!} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ from [Limit of a fraction of double factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584456/limit-of-a-fraction-of-double-factorials).

But my question is if there is a known better expression for $g(x)$ ?

Comment: it should be $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\sin ^{-1}(\cos (\pi  x))^2-\cos ^2(\pi  x)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\cos(\pi x)$ and consider 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2k}}{k} \frac{(2k-2)!!}{(2k-1)!!}= \left(\sin ^{-1}(t)\right)^2$$ Now, play with it.

**Edit**

In a comment, you ask how I managed this simplification. So, I give you the "cooking recipe" I was given long time ago by a fantastic professor. Here are the steps

- Expand the expression you have for a few terms (it also works with truncated series). Here, in your case, we have $$t^2+\frac{t^4}{3}+\frac{8 t^6}{45}+\frac{4 t^8}{35}$$
- Since it starts with $t^2$, apply the generalized binomial theorem for a power equal to $\frac 12$. This leads to $$t+\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{3 t^5}{40}+\frac{5 t^7}{112}+\cdots$$
- Does the result match a know Taylor series ? Here, the answer is *yes*

In my old notes, I found this one
$$x^{5/8}-\frac{5 x^{13/8}}{16}+\frac{275 x^{21/8}}{1536}-\frac{1015
   x^{29/8}}{8192}$$ So, apply the method and compute $$\left(x^{5/8}-\frac{5 x^{13/8}}{16}+\frac{275 x^{21/8}}{1536}-\frac{1015
   x^{29/8}}{8192} \right)^{\frac 85}=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$$ which is looking like $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! How can I prove that series expansion for $\left(\sin^{-1}(t)\right)^2$ ? Is it simply some manipulation of the Taylor series for $\sin^{-1}$?

Comment: @CMarius. I shall edit my "trick".

Answer (score 2):

If we apply Euler's series transformation (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersSeriesTransformation.html) to the Taylor series of $\arctan x,$ we obtain $$\arctan x=\frac{x}{1+x^2}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^k.$$ Setting $$x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$ and using $$\arctan\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\arcsin y,$$ this gives
$$\frac{\arcsin y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}y^{2k+1}.$$ Integrating, we get
$$\frac12(\arcsin y)^2=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}\frac{y^{2k+2}}{2k+2}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(2k-2)!!}{(2k-1)!!}\frac{y^{2k}}{2k}.$$